# How do I use get_content WordPress function?

Tags: wordpress

I am not able to fetch content while using the the_content WordPress function.

```
 <!-- Start the Loop. -->
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if ( in_category( '3' ) ) : ?>
        <div class="post-cat-three">
    <?php else : ?>
        <div class="post">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <!-- Display the date (November 16th, 2009 format) and a link to other posts by this posts author. -->
    <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></small>
    <!-- Display the Post's content in a div box. -->
    <div class="entry">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- Display a comma separated list of the Post's Categories. -->
    <p class="postmetadata"><?php _e( 'Posted in' ); ?> <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></p>
    </div> <!-- closes the first div box -->
    <!-- Stop The Loop (but note the "else:" - see next line). -->
 <?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <!-- The very first "if" tested to see if there were any Posts to -->
    <!-- display.  This "else" part tells what do if there weren't any. -->
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <!-- REALLY stop The Loop. -->
 <?php endif; ?>
```

I have really tried but get empty description result kindly help

Comment: I'm not having any problem running your. The issue is probably coming from somewhere else.

Comment: As amarinediary, I also tested your code and it works as expected for me. Double check that your posts actually have content to display.

Comment: @amarinediary I have tested on the live server and the local server still not working. Post content is there

Comment: @cabrerahector I have tested on the live server and the local server still not working. Post content is there

Comment: Where exactly are you using this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here a example fetch description from post in Wordpress

```
 <?php 
$categories = get_the_category( $id );
if( $categories ){
  // Assumes you just want the first category
  print 'You&#8217;re in the ' . $categories[ 0 ]->name . ' category';
}
?>
<ul>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 
        $attachments = get_posts( array(
            'post_type'   => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => null
        ) );
         
        if ( $attachments ) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                ?>
                <li><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' ); ?>
                    <p><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title ); ?></p>
                    
                </li>
                <?php
            }
        }
    endwhile; endif; ?>
</ul>
  <p><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title ); ?></p> <!-- do you need change post_title for description -->
```

Comment: Please, fix you negative click

Comment: If an answer isn't considered as helpful people have the right to downvote it, Kinslert. Don't ask them to "fix" the vote, instead make sure your answer does actually help the person asking the question.

Comment: @KinslertVirguez. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Comment: @Dominic in this example post_title  replace post_title  for post_description